# Const float** defined in header file

Tags: c++, dll

I have one dll which contains three computing methods and two static const containers. I do not define a class for embedding the code in the DLL. As it is scientific code, code calling the DLL will directly call the methods defined in it.

The two data structures can be const and static, and could be typed `float**`. For now, I defined this `QVector<QVector<float>>` in the header file of the class.

```
jsekseArr.reserve(3);
jsekseArr.resize(3);
jsekseArr[0] = QVector<float>() << 0 << 1 << 1 << 3;
jsekseArr[1] = QVector<float>() << 0 << 1 << 3 << 6;
jsekseArr[2] = QVector<float>() << 0 << 1 << 6 << 10;
```

But I want to be no more reliant on Qt. what is the best, cleaner way to define these data structures in the header file as float** ?

Should I create a struct for this matrix ?

Comment: How about `std::vector`? If the size is fixed at compile time `std::array` is also an option. Something like `std::array<float, 3>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2d vector try `std::vector<std::vector <float> >`